Cannot use a CONTAINS or FREETEXT predicate on table or indexed view 'MetadataConcepts' because it is not full-text indexed
I have two SQL Servers, a master and a backup.
I am trying to activate transactional database replication. I created a local publication of the database, on the backup server I created a subscription to synchronize the database.
When I look at the sync status I get an error message which is the title.
I don't know what to do to fix this error.
FYI I first restored a backup of the master server db before configuring replication
enter image description here
enter image description here
Thanks for your help
PS: I'm using SQL Server 2019 (v15.0.2000.5)
i have tried to note sync views , i need to synch this table.
what i expected is to not have this error anymore and the sync working

Perhaps https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/transactional-replication-sync-errorcannot-use-a-contains-or-freetext-predicate can help you out?
